# C++ User defined constructor for an abstract class

Tags: c++, design-patterns

In the code below (from Mark Joshi's C++ Design Design Patterns and Derivatives Pricing) could anyone explain why do we have to declare a default constructor, PayOff(){}, in the abstract class PayOff?

Thank you in advance
Regards

```
#ifndef PAYOFF3_H
#define PAYOFF3_H

class PayOff
{
public:

    PayOff(){};

    virtual double operator()(double Spot) const=0;
    virtual ~PayOff(){}
    virtual PayOff* clone() const=0;

private:

};

class PayOffCall : public PayOff
{
public:

    PayOffCall(double Strike_);

    virtual double operator()(double Spot) const;
    virtual ~PayOffCall(){}
    virtual PayOff* clone() const;

private:

    double Strike;

};


class PayOffPut : public PayOff
{
public:

    PayOffPut(double Strike_);

    virtual double operator()(double Spot) const;
    virtual ~PayOffPut(){}
    virtual PayOff* clone() const;

private:

    double Strike;

};

#endif
```

Comment: If you don't define one, compiler will generate it for you. Anyway, here a default ctor is needed by the derived class.

Comment: disclaimer* I'm not a c++ developer but I'm pretty sure its generally bad practise to have public constructors in an abstract class. Protected ones yes but Public? An abstract class is one that cannot be Instantiated. Typically if you wished all your Implementations to expose a certain constructor you would expose it in an interface and ensure that your abstract class implements this.

Comment: yes I agree with Mark

Comment: So i just don't need to declare it in this case?